# Send push notification according to mobile OS

Tags: php, web-services, push-notification

I am working on webservices for an application which is being developed for android and iphone.

I am stuck at a point where I have to send the push notifications. I am saving the device token(IOS) or gcm registeration id (android) according to the device on which user gets logged in.

Now my problem is how will I distinguish between the two at the time of push notification since procedure for push notifications for GCM and APNS is different.
Dont tell me about user agent because it will not work in my case because these notifications will be sent using cron job.

Do I need to save device type in database or is there some other alternative. ..?

Hope I am clear with my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do and what I have done.

If you are storing the ID's in the database it should be very easy to distinguish the two. If you are keeping them in the same table but different fields then just use a different name for the columns.
Save the ID's according to device type. Just don't have a generic column for Push Notification ID use two. I save the device ID according to type and the user's member ID with it. So even if they register with multiple devices it will send it to all their devices android or ios. Or I can just select all and send to every registered user.

Here are some examples. One example using multiple id columns and one using a single id column with another column for type.

`gcm_id` and `apn_id` as column names in the DB where the keys are stored one for android and one for iOS.

Then when you are ready to send out notifications you can do a select query based on whatever criteria you want.

e.g. To send to a large group of users, you could do the following. Simple example not full code.

```
 $result = "SELECT * FROM notification_table"
```

Then with some PHP iterate through the array and send out the notifications.

```
foreach($result as $key=>$id){

  if($key == "gcm_id"){
   //do android push here using the $id or run a function passing $id to it
  }elseif($key == "apn_id"){
   //do apple push here using the $id or run a function passing $id to it
  }    

 }
```

Or another option is to save the device type and use one ID field. So your table might have something like

```
push_id | dev_type | member_id
```

When saving it to the database be sure to specify the device type. It could be how ever you want. `dev_type` could be a text/character varying or even an integer field and you specify a number ID for each type. However you want to keep up with it. I might go with character varying and use `android / ios` as values so that it's easier for me to remember than a code.

Then do the same thing except filter by device type.

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM notification_table"
```

Then with some PHP iterate through the array and send out the notifications.

```
foreach($result as $res){

  if($res["dev_type"] == "android"){
   //do android push here using the $res["push_id"] or pass it to a function
  }elseif($res["dev_type"] == "ios"){
   //do apple push here using the $res["push_id"] or pass it to a function
  }    

 }
```

Or limiting it to a certain user for say new private message. Sample not full code

```
$result = "SELECT * FROM notification_table WHERE mem_id='12345'";
```

Then call a function or however you want to handle it.

Personally I would create two functions, one for GCM and one for APN. Then call the functions when going through the foreach loop depending on type. Sample functions passing the ID and a message to send.

```
function push_gcm($id,$message){

//do stuff

}

function push_apn($id,$message){

//do stuff

}
```

I personally would not rely on anything like length of ID or anything like that to determine type. Save the type with the ID like with one of the examples above. Hope this helps some and gives you a start on sorting them.